# R cannot open file with cfa()

Tags: r, rstudio

Trying to complete a confirmatory factor analysis right now. Have been reading [the tutorial](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/tutorial.pdf/%22tutorial%20here%22) but am unable to overcome the following error that comes after the fit command:

```
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") : cannot open file ' independence =~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
          therapies =~ x5': No such file or directory
```

Code I am using:

```
df <- data.frame(df.raw)
carl.model <- ' independence =~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
                therapies =~ x5 + x6'

fit <- cfa(carl.model, data=df)

summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

Comment: I don't know for a fact what is going on since you don't provide the data to test with, but I suspect you should fix the model syntax by removing the extra white space. As far as I know `lavaan` model syntax is pretty robust to funniness like that but it's the only thing that jumps out at me.  In fact I didn't even think that the first argument of `lavaan`  `cfa()` could be a file so I'm wondering if you might have the wrong package loaded perhaps?  (I'm only assuming you're using `lavaan` because the model syntax you're using and the tutorial you link to require it.

Comment: The code youve shown look okay. How did you read in your data `df.raw` ... did it read in?. Have you tried starting a new R session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have another library with the same function. 
Specify that you are talking about lavaan

lavaan::cfa(carl.model, data=df)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting and clearing workspace solved this problem. I did not change anything to the above code and now runs cleanly.